# I am Using DSO Framer with load office 365 word document. but the document open out of DSO framer

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office365, dsoframer

i attached screen shots for erroroutput(using office 365 word) and actual output(ms-word2007)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestOffice365
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fmrDocEdit.Open(@"D:\test\TestOffice365\TestOffic365\test.doc");
           
            this.Height += 1;   // To refresh the framer
        }
    }
}
```

[Error_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijthd.png)
[Actual_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrdKg.png)